# How to convert a Unix Timestamp from a Postgresql column into Python (for plotting)?

Tags: python, postgresql, unix, timestamp, utc

I got a Postgresql Table with couple Unix Timestamp rows for example(1537510150) which I want to convert to a readable timestamp in Python. I want them to be in the X axis.
The Unix Timestamps are in the "messungnr" column.

My Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import psycopg2
import datetime as dt
import time
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

conn = psycopg2.connect(host = "10.50.56.154", port = "5432", dbname= "Messwerte", user="****", password="****")

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('''SELECT messungnr FROM Messungen_2018_09_21''')
rows1 = cur.fetchall()



cur.execute('''SELECT fs22si_1_ch_1_sensor_1_ch_6_crackmeter_mikrometer FROM Messungen_2018_09_21''')
rows2 = cur.fetchall()    

plt.plot(rows1, rows2)
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('Timestamp')
plt.ylabel('Dehnung')
plt.title('Messung_2018_09_21')
plt.legend()
plt.show()

conn.close()
```

Do you have any idea? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Which field is it you're talking about? and what is the value of that field? `print(variable)` and `print(type(variable))`? You should be getting a `datetime` object from psycopg2? [psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.RealDictCursor) might help you as well.

Comment: It is about the cur.execute('''SELECT messungnr FROM Messungen_2018_09_21''')
rows1 = cur.fetchall() which i want to convert into a readable timestamp.

Comment: Ok, so you want to convert a `datetime` object into `time()` or `strftime()` object? If so, what's wrong with `rows1[row_number][column].strftime("...")`? Because `rows1` is a list of all the rows, you have to select which row/result to do the actual `.strftime()` on. And you can do `.strftime()` directly on a column in a row. Remember, you're doing `.fetchall()` which returns all the rows, so you have to select the row, and then the column and THEN do `.strftime(format)`.

Comment: The datetime object in my Postgresql column is like this (1537510150) and i want to convert this into a readable timestamp in Python for my plott(X axis).

Comment: When i do it like your example i get : TypeError: an integer is required (got type list)

Comment: Google that error message, and figure out why you're trying to do `variable[list]` instead of `variable[integer]`. And find out where you're passing in the wrong argument. I'd start with doing `print(variable)` and `print(parameter1)` to figure out what the variable looks like and what the parameter you're giving it look like.

Comment: Hm okay thanks i try my best, but I am not that good in python :D

Comment: You're doing fine, I think I know what's wrong but it's better if you learn the ways to find the errors yourself as well. Doing a simple `print(<something>)` is always a really good start. Especially if you get errors like these. Literally do a `print()` on everything you're working with and putting in to stuff, you'll soon see the problem. Or do `print(type(<something>))` and that will tell you some more things about the stuff you're fiddlign with.

Comment: Hopefully I will :D Thank you @Torxed !

Comment: I tried coulpe things now and still have no clue how to fix that formatting problem :(

Comment: got it :D

dateconv = np.vectorize(dt.datetime.fromtimestamp)
rows1 = dateconv(rows1)